# ESP32 Alexa Integration; Cannot correctly control more than one device

Tags: esp32

I created a garage door opener recently that is controllable through Alexa, using this library: https://github.com/Aircoookie/Espalexa

Everything is operating as expected, meaning I was able to detect my device and control the garage (using routines).

The issue came when I went to integrate Alexa into another previously completed/operational project. I was able to successfully discover and control the second board, kind of.

At this point I have added two ESP32 boards to Alexa, named differently of course. When I went to test the second board(meaning that it was successully discovered, and the ESP was receiving most commands) I noticed that Alexa was also opening my garage. If i unplugged my garage door opener(first board to be added) the second board starts to all receive commands, although degraded; for example;

In the above noted library Alexa should be able to control 'brightness' of dimmable lights. Of course this device is not a dimmable light but for the purposes of the integration, this library emulates smart lights. I am never able to see Alexa trying to set a brightness whose value is not 0.

Example, this is successfully executed on board 2, sometimes only when board 1 is unplugged:

```
void alexa_change_hdmi(EspalexaDevice* d) {
    Serial.println("Executing");
    uint8_t brightness = d->getValue();
    Serial.println(brightness);
    doing more things....
```

Here, brightness is always printed as 0.

So, after I added board X to alexa and tested successfully, I added board Y to alexa. Board X receives both commands for X and Y most of the time. Vice versa if board Y is the only device on. This is not intended by design. I would like to control them separately(preferably through the use of one alexa device).

I'm not sure if this (^) is related to the inability of Alexa to tell the two distinct board apart. I'm not sure why i'm not getting a brightness level, I would like to use it to make decisions, example;

```
if (brightness == '2.55') {
unsigned int irSignal[] = {9000, 4450, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 550, 600, 500, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1650, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 500, 600, 550, 550, 600, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 550, 600, 1650, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550, 1700, 550}; // NEC FF906F
irsend.sendRaw(irSignal, sizeof(irSignal) / sizeof(irSignal[0]), khz);
}
```

Has anyone seen this issue integrating several ESP32 devices with one Amazon Echo? Has anyone ever gotten brightness to successfully pass into the function that alexa triggers?

### EDIT*

After doing some more testing it appears that ESPALEXAWITHASYNCWEBSERVER is causing Alexa to not be able to differentiate between the distinct boards. This implies that if you want to use more than one device with this library, you cannot use the async example.

As a side effect, brightness always returns 0 when not using the async library, meaning you can really only use this library to control on and off state, not brightness, if you have more than one ESP device. ASYNC example correctly returns brightness, all other examples return 0, no matter what you set the brightness to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library , in past i have used 5 device at a time

[fauxmoesp](https://bitbucket.org/xoseperez/fauxmoesp/src/master/)

Comment: Faumo is not working for me, unable to detect devices